# how to make a full width slider without loosing quality?

Tags: slider

i am trying to create a full width slider for only images with text. My slider is full width but needs a specific height (example 400px)because it is going to be displayed as the banner of my website.

The problem is that the images look blurry and i dont know the proper size or perhaps the code to prevent this.

This is what i have so far as for my html and the images's size

```
 <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="full-width">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="slide">
                <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. <br>Curabitur molestie elit et ultricies vehicula.</div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1020/400/sports" width="1020" height="400">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div>Nullam dictum magna sapien, sed adipiscing nibh. <br>Curabitur molestie elit et ultricies vehicula.</div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1020/400/city" width="1020" height="400">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div>Donec malesuada hendrerit velit, sed consequat. <br>Curabitur molestie elit et ultricies vehicula.</div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1020/400/cats" width="1020" height="400">
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <div>Maecenas augue dui, rhoncus a blandit non. <br>Curabitur molestie elit et ultricies vehicula.</div>
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1020/400/business" width="1020" height="400">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <a href="#" class="left">&lt;</a>
            <a href="#" class="right">&gt;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-nav"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as for my css:

```
.full-width {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
.full-width,
.full-width .slide img {
    width: 100%;
}
.full-width:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
.full-width .inner {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=00)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=00);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.full-width .slide {
    float: left;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.full-width .slide img {
    height: auto;
}
.full-width .slide div {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 5%;
    left: 0;
    width: 90%;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.full-width .slide div p {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
.full-width .controls a {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -46px;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 0 10px 2px 7px;
    line-height: 40px;
    *display: none;
}
.full-width .controls a.left {
    left: 0px;
}
.full-width .controls a.right {
    right: 0px;
}
.full-width .slide-nav {
    *display: none;
    font-size: 75px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.full-width .slide-nav span {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ccc;
}
.full-width .slide-nav span.current {
    color: #333;
}
.lt-ie9 .full-width p,
.lt-ie9 .full-width .controls a {
    background: url('bg-trans.png') repeat;
    _background: #333;
}
```

what i need to know if it is a matter of adjusting only the image size although i tried that already and didnt worked or if it remains in the code. 
thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This is kind of confusing as to what the problem is.  Is the problem that the slider is not functioning or is the problem that the image quality is degraded while in the slider when it is full width?

Comment: If you are having problem with slider functionality (motion) then please provide the code you tried to work with, there may be a simple typo or naming problem that will be easy to fix and causes everything to completely fail.  It's hard to know without seeing what you were trying to do.  Not sure what tutorial you may have tried, but this is a simple JQuery slider example, http://www.basic-slider.com/.

Comment: Yeah sorry, what i meant is that the slider is working but the pictures are all blurry, what i need is to know the size to cover any screen size as you can see i have my images 1200 x 400 px, but its not working, which would be a good size for my images?

Comment: Based on the HTML above, the ideal size for your images would be 1020 width and 400 height so it matches the sizes used in the IMG tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the images are getting blurry at larger sizes, you will need to produce an image with the dimensions of the maximum area you want it to cover.  This way when it is at full size the quality will be clear.

When you decrease the screen size, the image size will likely be decreasing too.  In my experience it is better to start large and scale to a smaller size to preserve the clarity of the image, so you should approach it that way.

If the problem is that it is not scaling correctly because the proportions are off because of the fixed height, then you will need to produce images with the correct proportions to support the size you need.  This is most easily done with image editing software like Photoshop rather than making adjustments in HTML.